# DescribeInstanceTypes fails with access denied for some AWS regions

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to get the Instance Details with the Amazon go SDK.

However, I'm getting this error for some regions.

> AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access
> credentials ...

A search on that error reveals that I need to do something different with the credentials.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-validate-access-credentials/

It's not entirely clear what I'm meant to do as there are no examples that I can find that do this in go.

How do I modify the below code to remove the error?

```
func (service *CloudClusterInfoService) AmazonEksFetchInfo(accessKey, secretAccessKey string) (*AmazonEksInfo, error) {
    log.Debug("[cloud] [message: sending cloud provider info request] [provider: amazon-eks]")

    resolver := endpoints.DefaultResolver()
    partitions := resolver.(endpoints.EnumPartitions).Partitions()
    eksInfo := &AmazonEksInfo{}

    for _, p := range partitions {
        // Get a list of regions where the Amazon EKS service is available
        if eks, ok := p.Services()["eks"]; ok {
            for _, region := range eks.Regions() {
                eksInfo.Regions = append(eksInfo.Regions, portaineree.Pair{
                    Name:  region.Description(),
                    Value: region.ID(),
                })

                log.Infof("Region: %s, URL: %s", region.ID(), endpoint.URL)

                sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
                    Region:      aws.String(region.ID()),
                    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey, ""),
                })

                if err != nil {
                    log.Errorf("[cloud] [message: failed to create AWS session] [provider: amazon-eks] [region: %s] [error: %s]", id, err)
                    continue
                }

                svc := ec2.New(sess)

                params := &ec2.DescribeInstanceTypesInput{
                    Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
                        {
                            Name:   aws.String("current-generation"),
                            Values: []*string{aws.String("true")},
                        },
                    },
                }

                types, err := svc.DescribeInstanceTypes(params)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Errorf("[cloud] [message: failed to get instance types] [provider: amazon-eks] [region: %s] [error: %s]", id, err)
                    continue
                }

                for _, v := range types.InstanceTypes {
                    fmt.Println("Instance Type: ", *v.InstanceType)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return eksInfo, nil
}
```

Comment: Is this running on a VM of some sort? Where is this running? Ensure the date time of the host machine running this application is accurate & up to date.

Comment: If it is, then where are you getting `accessToken` from here? Is it permanent? Temporary? Generated by you? From an EC2 machine? Where does it come from?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - accessToken and secretAccessToken are generated from the security credentials section for my user.  "Create Access Key".  The link above suggests it has something to do with AWS STS.  It has absolutely nothing to do with the date and time of the host machine.  Only some regions are failing, not all.  See the link.

Comment: Are you running this on EC2 or locally?

Comment: Go into IAM > account settings > security token service > change “ Region compatibility of session tokens” for “Global Endpoint” to all regions; try again, that should work.

Comment: This is local, not within the aws cloud

Comment: I understand but you generated your credentials from the console? Console, API, SDK or the AWS CLI? Try the above and then regenerate your credentials please

Comment: I've discovered that I was using the v1 api.  I'm not having these issues yet with v2.  The v1 api is giving me a list of regions that are not enabled for my location.  Thats basically the problem I think.  v2 api filters those out by default.  Seems cleaner so far

Comment: Glad you got it sorted